# Unable to import Quandl on Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, quandl

I am unable to import quandl in Spyder, running python 3.5 with Anaconda.

```
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling quandl, however I am only able to use to use in Sublime Text or Rodeo, and receive the following error when I try to run the same script in Spyder.

```
ImportError: No module named 'quandl'
```

For reference, I originally installed quandl via:

```
pip install quandl
```

And then tried the conda install after I received the first Spyder ImportError

```
conda install quandl
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy the script path in the anaconda folder eg: `C:\Anaconda\Scripts`

Go to the *controlpanel\System\Advanced system settings\Environment Variables\Path* then hit edit and paste the path you copied and restart the cmd line.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Anaconda Prompt` (You can access it from start menu)

Type in:

```
conda install -c anaconda quandl
```

this will install quandl module. Worked fine for me. :-)